Why was LAMMPS simulation aborted with bus error message
I used LAMMPS to do the thermal conductance calculation. This is my input file content.
variable         kb equal 8.617333262e-5
variable         t equal 300.0
variable         th equal 400.0
variable         tc equal 200.0

units            metal
dimension        3
newton           on
boundary         p p p
atom_style       charge
neighbor         2.0 bin
timestep         0.0005

read_data        atomic_structure_atomic

pair_style        hybrid comb3 polar_off lj/cut 12.0 airebo 3.0
pair_coeff       * * comb3 ./ffield.comb3.NiAlO O Al NULL NULL NULL NULL&
                 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
pair_coeff       * * airebo ./CH.airebo NULL NULL C C C C C C C C C &
                 C
pair_coeff       1 3 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 4 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 5 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 6 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 7 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 8 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 9 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 10 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 11 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 12 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       2 3 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 4 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 5 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 6 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 7 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 8 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 9 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 10 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 11 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 12 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846

compute          ke1 all ke/atom
variable         tem atom c_ke1/1.5/${kb}

thermo           1000
thermo_style     custom step temp pxx pyy pzz press vol
velocity         all create $t 898758 mom yes rot yes dist gaussian

min_style        cg
minimize         1.0e-8 1.0e-8 1000000 1000000

#1st euqilibrium in NPT ensamble
thermo           2000
thermo_style     custom step temp pe ke etotal vol pxx pyy pzz press
fix              1 all npt temp $t $t 0.05 aniso 0.0 0.0 0.5
dump             xyz_npt all xyz 1000 dump_npt.xyz
dump_modify      xyz_npt element O Al C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10
run              200000
unfix            1
undump           xyz_npt
reset_timestep   0
write_data       atomic_structure_atomic_npt.dat

#2nd equilibrium in NVT ensamble
thermo           2000
thermo_style     custom temp pe ke etotal vol pxx pyy pzz press
fix              2 all nvt temp $t $t 0.05
dump             xyz_nvt all xyz 1000 dump_nvt.xyz
dump_modify      xyz_nvt element O Al C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10
run              200000
unfix            2
undump           xyz_nvt
reset_timestep   0

#Dividing the zone
variable         zbl equal zlo
variable         zbh equal zhi
variable         nla equal 314
variable         sca equal 1/${nla}
variable         len equal ${zbh}-${zbl}
variable         dz equal ${len}/${nla}
variable         zll equal ${zbl}+${dz}*2
variable         zlh equal ${zbl}+${dz}*6
variable         zrl equal ${zbh}-${dz}*6
variable         zrh equal ${zbh}-${dz}*2

region           reg_whole block INF INF INF INF ${zbl} ${zbh} units box
region           lef_fixed block INF INF INF INF INF ${zll} units box
region           hot block INF INF INF INF ${zll} ${zlh} units box
region           cold block INF INF INF INF ${zrl} ${zrh} units box
region           rig_fixed block INF INF INF INF ${zrh} INF units box
region           fixed_both union 2 lef_fixed rig_fixed

group            fixed region fixed_both
group            hot region hot
group            cold region cold
group            move subtract all fixed

reset_timestep   0
change_box       all boundary p p f

velocity         fixed set 0 0 0
fix              fixed fixed setforce 0 0 0

fix              3 hot langevin ${th} ${th} 0.05 14565 tally yes
fix              4 cold langevin ${tc} ${tc} 0.05 16576 tally yes
fix              5 all nve

variable         time equal step
variable         el equal f_3
variable         er equal f_4

compute          6 all chunk/atom bin/1d z lower ${sca} units reduced
fix              7 all ave/chunk 1 10000 10000 6 v_tem file profile.heat
thermo           2000
thermo_style     custom step temp ke pe etotal press vol
dump             xyz_nve all xyz 1000 dump_nve.xyz
dump_modify      xyz_nve element O Al C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10
run              200000
unfix            7
undump           xyz_nve
reset_timestep   0

fix              8 all ave/chunk 1 10000 10000 6 v_tem file time_average_temperature.dat
fix              eou all print 2000 "${time} ${el} ${er}" file energy.dat title "time e1 e2" screen no

thermo           20000
thermo_style     custom step temp ke pe etotal press vol
dump             fin all xyz 20000 fin.xyz
dump_modify      fin element O Al C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10
run              200000

This is the error message file.
srun: error: c324: task 4: Bus error
srun: error: c323: task 3: Bus error
[c320:29691:0:29691] rc_verbs_iface.c:65   send completion with error: transport retry counter exceeded qpn 0x54e7a wrid 0x32 vendor_err 0x81
[c322:13536:0:13536] rc_verbs_iface.c:65   send completion with error: transport retry counter exceeded qpn 0x4bff wrid 0x13 vendor_err 0x81
==== backtrace (tid:  29691) ====
 0 0x000000000004cb95 ucs_debug_print_backtrace()  ???:0
 1 0x0000000000024df8 uct_rc_iface_verbs_cleanup_rx()  ???:0
 2 0x0000000000025a30 uct_rc_verbs_iface_post_recv_always()  ???:0
 3 0x000000000002158a ucp_worker_progress()  ???:0
 4 0x0000000000009ab1 mlx_ep_progress()  mlx_ep.c:0
 5 0x000000000001e8dd ofi_cq_progress()  osd.c:0
 6 0x000000000001f59b ofi_cq_readfrom()  osd.c:0
 7 0x00000000006594c6 fi_cq_read()  /usr/include/rdma/fi_eq.h:385
 8 0x00000000001ab58b MPIDI_Progress_test()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/src/ch4_progress.c:181
 9 0x00000000001ab58b MPID_Progress_test()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/src/ch4_progress.c:236
10 0x00000000001ab58b MPID_Progress_wait()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/src/ch4_progress.c:297
11 0x00000000007f7518 MPIR_Wait_impl()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpi/request/wait.c:40
12 0x00000000007f7518 MPID_Wait()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/include/mpidpost.h:188
13 0x00000000007f7518 MPIR_Wait()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpi/request/wait.c:95
14 0x00000000007f7518 PMPI_Wait()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpi/request/wait.c:190
15 0x000000000140a576 LAMMPS_NS::Dump::write()  /data/app/lammps/2024/lammps-7Feb2024/src/Obj_mpi/../dump.cpp:506
16 0x00000000007ec32d LAMMPS_NS::Output::write()  /data/app/lammps/2024/lammps-7Feb2024/src/Obj_mpi/../output.cpp:391
17 0x000000000118b5ae LAMMPS_NS::Verlet::run()  /data/app/lammps/2024/lammps-7Feb2024/src/Obj_mpi/../verlet.cpp:356
18 0x0000000000e0ca45 LAMMPS_NS::Run::command()  /data/app/lammps/2024/lammps-7Feb2024/src/Obj_mpi/../run.cpp:176
19 0x0000000000594501 LAMMPS_NS::Input::execute_command()  /data/app/lammps/2024/lammps-7Feb2024/src/Obj_mpi/../input.cpp:868
20 0x0000000000594e3c LAMMPS_NS::Input::file()  /data/app/lammps/2024/lammps-7Feb2024/src/Obj_mpi/../input.cpp:313
21 0x00000000004bc1e8 main()  /data/app/lammps/2024/lammps-7Feb2024/src/Obj_mpi/../main.cpp:77
22 0x0000000000022555 __libc_start_main()  ???:0
23 0x00000000004bdb7e _start()  ???:0
=================================
[mpiexec@c320.hpc] HYD_sock_write (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/sock/hydra_sock_intel.c:360): write error (Bad file descriptor)
[mpiexec@c320.hpc] HYD_sock_write (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/sock/hydra_sock_intel.c:360): write error (Bad file descriptor)
[mpiexec@c320.hpc] HYD_sock_write (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/sock/hydra_sock_intel.c:360): write error (Bad file descriptor)
[mpiexec@c320.hpc] HYD_sock_write (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/sock/hydra_sock_intel.c:360): write error (Bad file descriptor)
[mpiexec@c320.hpc] HYD_sock_write (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/sock/hydra_sock_intel.c:360): write error (Bad file descriptor)
[mpiexec@c320.hpc] HYD_sock_write (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/sock/hydra_sock_intel.c:360): write error (Bad file descriptor)
[mpiexec@c320.hpc] HYD_sock_write (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/sock/hydra_sock_intel.c:360): write error (Bad file descriptor)
[mpiexec@c320.hpc] HYD_sock_write (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/sock/hydra_sock_intel.c:360): write error (Bad file descriptor)
[mpiexec@c320.hpc] wait_proxies_to_terminate (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/mpiexec/intel/i_mpiexec.c:527): downstream from host c320 exited with status 135

I do not understand why the calculation was terminated with the bus error message. Would anyone please give me some suggestions/comments?
Any help appreciated.

Are you reserving enough memory for your job?

@Anyon Thank you for the reply. In your opinion, this is due to memory issue of the cluster; not from my input file. Am I correct?

I've never used LAMMPS, so I cannot comment on the input file. Others might be able to. I'm just working on the assumption that the output is correct in noting that a bus error has occurred, meaning that a process is trying to access memory it cannot possibly access. In my experience, the easiest thing to check is whether it occurs because you're simply running out of memory. This can be followed by looking into whether your call to mpiexec/mpirun is correct, but this diagnosis tends to have more steps like trying running without parallelization, or parallel on single vs multiple nodes.

@Anyon Thank you for your suggestions.
